# Is it possible to have android ID length less than 16?

Tags: android, udid, android-identifiers

I have used [Android_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) as unique ID during my app registration. Since Android ID is 64 bit hex string, I considered it's length will be 16 and validating it during registration. But few of the android devices had the length as 15. If its 64 bit hex String, how can the length be 15? Please someone give me a clear information about Android ID length.

Comment: What do you mean by `Android ID`? How do you obtain it?

Comment: @karan This is possible in case of emulators and rooted devices as ANDROID_ID can be easily modified. Can you tell me for which devices you found the length as 15? In my case a smartphone model VIVO Y21L has 15 character Android ID.

Comment: @Vishal Vyas I am using King Wear KW88 smart watch. If android id can be changed, do you have any idea in which system file I can check that.

Comment: @Robert, That link might be an answer too. For now I will follow the answer suggested in that link. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @Prerak Sola: By Android ID I meant -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID